# Use awk/sed scripting to extract function parameters

Tags: python, bash, sed, awk

I have Python code from which I want to extract HTTP parameters.

In the following: how can I leave the `def` lines alone, but from remaining lines preserve only what is within `params['...']` perhaps with multiple `params['...']` on one line:

Input:

```
def delete_bazooka (request):
    BType.objects.get(id=params['id']).delete()
    BType.objects.get(name=params['name']).delete()
def create_bazooka (request):
  s = Skill.objects.get(id=params['skill'])
  l = Level.objects.get(id=params['level'])
  bt = BType.objects.get(name=params['type'])
  b = Bazooka(type=qt, bin=b, bin_sequence=b.count, text=params['text'], explanation=params['chocolate'], passage=p)
def delete_hoop (request):
  h = Hoop.objects.get(id=params['id'])
```

Desired Output:

```
def delete_bazooka (request):
id
name
def create_bazooka (request):
skill
level
type
text chocolate
def delete_hoop (request):
id
```

Comment: you mean you want to  print the value of params keys? That would be simply: print params["id"], or if there are multiple ones: for key in params: print params[key]

Comment: @Pawelmhm no, i am analyzing python code using `awk`/`sed`. i cannot run it. i want to document it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep` `with the E (regexp) and o (only matching) flags:

```
grep -Eo "(?def .*|'[a-z]+')" test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F\' '{$0=/^def/?$0:$2" "$4}1' test.txt
```

Comment: this hardcodes for 1 or 2 but fails for n params on 1 line; the other answer chosen as correct works for n. upvoted regardless because my id is no_answer_not_upvoted ;-)